# How do you include 2 report formats on a single reporting services email subscription?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a subscription set up in sql server reporting services to email me a report every morning in **mthml** format, which outlook will render out in an email. I also want this report to be emailed to me in **pdf** format so that I can save it.

Is it possible to set up a single subscription that includes both a **pdf** and **mthml** report format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this would require a separate subscription because you are forced to choose a single "render format" per subscription.

[options http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/4082/ssrsoptions.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/4082/ssrsoptions.png)

Now since the only goal of the PDF would be to save it, why not setup the second subscription to save to a network share rather than email?  You could then simply view the report (MHTML) and look at the network for what you would have manually saved.

In this post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/c59f7a34-1201-4c75-a6f3-783bbd76e60a), someone suggested a data driven subscription may be able to do this for you.  I've not spent time in that area before.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150.aspx) is an article on MSDN about data driven subscriptions.

Comment: well, I simplified the "saving" part... bascially we want users to be able to view the report on a mobile device, and the emails on a mobile device don't allow you to view mhtml format, so sending it in pdf would solve that because then they could just open it. but we still want mhtml because outlook formats those correctly and the user doesn't have to open a file to view the report on their desktop.

Comment: i'll look at those links that you posted.

Comment: Make sure you have SSRS Enterprise if you want to use data driven subscriptions.